# How to Switch between namenodes in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Pseudomode Cluster:

Suppose first time I created a namenode on Machine "A" with name "Root1".
This will create a HDFS on tha machine.
Now i copy some file to HDFS using copyFromLocal and do some mapreduce.

Now i need to change some /conf files. 
I'll change config file and to make them effective I formatted namenode with name "Root2".
If i browse the HDFS , it will be empty (means it will not contain those which copied earlier for "Root1").

If I want to see old file (for "Root1"), is there any way to switch to that HDFS or namenode (Root2 to Root1 ) ??

Answer (score 0):

To be clear. Did you launch the another namenode on your machine ?

Type `sudo jps` in console or http://localhost:50070 in browser and check if you have more than one datanode. If there is just one node you lost your data from HDFS. If you have two namenodes you can check the filesystem in Internet browser on http://localhost:50070.

[Here](http://bigdata.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/hadoop-cookbook-4-how-to-run-multiple-data-nodes-on-one-machine/) is instruction how to launch more than one datanode on one machine.